# Is this slightly different proof to Hibert's Theorem "different enough"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question

**I generally try and think up slightly different proofs to the material that I read in order to grasp some deeper possible insight, and then painstakingly record them in a latex document. I've been going through [this](http://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Hilbert_s_basis_theorem.html) proof of Hilbert's Basis Theorem, and thought up a slightly altered proof (a generalisation, in ways). Is this proof different enough to be called a new one, or should I not bother recording such seemingly trivial altered proofs in the future?**

Let us assume that $R$ is a left-neotherian ring. We have the polynomial ring $R[X]$. Take an ideal that is not finitely generated- $I$. Generate a sequence of polynomials $f_{1},f_{2},f_{3},\dots f_{i}$ such that $f_{j+1}$ is the minimal polynomial in $I\setminus (f_{1},f_{2},f_{3},\dots f_{j})$.

*Let us construct another ideal- generated by coefficients $a_{i}$ of $f_{i}$ such that the coefficient selected from $f_{i+1}$ belongs to a $\geq$ power of $x$ as compared to $f_{i}$.* This ideal $(a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},\dots )$ will have a finite set of generators $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},\dots a_{N}$.

If the ideal $i$ is not finitely generated, then it is not equal to $(f_{1},f_{2},f_{3},\dots f_{N})$, although the converse is not necessarily true. This means that $I\setminus (f_{1},f_{2},f_{3},\dots f_{N})$ contains another minimal polynomial $f_{N+1}$. We select a coefficient $a_{N+1}$ belonging to $x^{j_{N+1}}$. We know $a_{N+1}=u_{1}a_{1}+u_{2}a_{2}+u_{3}a_{3}+\dots u_{N}a_{N}$, where $u_{i}\in R[X]$. *The polynomial $f_{N+1}-\sum{u_{i}f_{i}x^{\displaystyle{j_{N+1}-j_{i}}}}$, which is a part of $I\setminus (f_{1},f_{2},f_{3},\dots f_{N})$, is missing the term $a_{N+1}x^{j_{N+1}}$ that the minimal polynomial in $I\setminus (f_{1},f_{2},f_{3},\dots f_{N})$ was expected to have.* This is a contradiction.

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: All the arguments are pretty analogous to the ones given in the [link](http://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Hilbert_s_basis_theorem.html).

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated.